# How to add minutes to a specific date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've this date:

> 2015-10-27 10:50:00

And in the minutes variabile I've this valorization: 30

Now for add minutes to the date initially I convert my date in the format that I want like this:

```
var dbdate = moment(moment(appointment['end_datetime']).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));

dbdate.add({minutes: min});
```

But this return the same date above. NB: the appointment ['end_datetime'] contain the date above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say you have `30` in `minutes` -- what's in `min`?

Comment: Minutes is the momentjs parameter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont format it first

```
var dbdate = moment(appointment['end_datetime']);
dbdate.add({minutes: min});
// format dbdate just before using it/displaying it
```

This assumes you have the value you want to add in minutes stored in a variable `min`. In the code above the `minutes` is the property name, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dbdate = moment(appointment['end_datetime']).add(30, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

or using your variable

```
var dbdate = moment(appointment['end_datetime']).add(min, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

reference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS Date() method can do the trick.

```
var date= new Date('2015-10-27 10:50:00');
```

value in date now is 'Tue Oct 27 2015 10:50:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+30);
```

and now date variable has increased datetime to 30 minutes.